# Excel conditional formatting - color scales

Tags: excel

I'd like to color cells according to their value (cf conditional formatting - color scales) in the style menu of Excel 2007 to newer.

It works fine and the effect is wonderful when you have a wide range of data with fairly distributed values.

However, the column I am formatting conditionally is the result of some computation. Sometimes I get N/A values because one of my input is N/A, and sometimes I get the exception "division by zero" as my cells are the result of a division. In these scenarios, i don't get any colors at all.

Is there a way to ignore these problematic cells that happen sometimes, leave them blank and process colours for the rest of them ?

Thank you guys ! ;)

A picture of when it works fine : [image: column coloured with regard to values]

Another picture showing a problematic cell cancelling the colouring : [image]

I'm looking for an Excel solution to the problem, which I can then record as macro to port to my C# application. But if someone has a nice workaround in C#, I'd be happy too (i.e. I use `ToColourScalePercentile` on the range, I was thinking to maybe remove problematic cells from the range somehow)

Comment: You could alter your formula by wrapping it in an IF() such that in the case of error the cell is left blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use IsError function to check if there is N/A and in case there is leave the cell empty, otherwise put the value there.

Comment: Excellent, if I put a default text with this it doesn't consider it and works smoothly. Many thanks Michel.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using 2007 you can wrap your calculation in the iferror() function would look like:

```
=iferror(your calculation here, 0)
```

This way if your caculation evaluates to an error it will substitute the second argument.  You can use 0 or "" to have it blank.

Comment: IMHO ``IfError`` (introduced with Excel 2007) is preferable as the implementation is much simpler than the ``IF(IsError(...))`` construct.